# What does "calling methods directly instead of through a reference" mean?

Tags: actionscript-3

I just went through [a slideshow from Grant Skinner](http://gskinner.com/talks/quick/) on improving performance of ActionScript. One tip he gave was written as, "Call methods directly instead of through a reference." I don't quite understand what this means...

Does is mean to avoid making a function call to a variable referencing a function object?

```
var someObjectsDoSomethingMethod:Function = someObj.doSomething;
someObjectsDoSomethingMethod();
```

Or do avoid making a function call to a variable referencing another object, which possesses that method?

```
var someObject:Function = someObj;
someObject.doSomething();
```

Or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, he's saying that, if possible (especially for method calls within loops), that the fastest way is to not use a method call at all (see Slide 51), but if you must then try to directly call a method (slide 52). While that isn't always practical, or desired, there is some overhead depending on how you invoke a method and what object you are invoking it off of.

The biggest take away is that closures are really expensive.

For example:

```
WithAnonymousFunction.Go(function() { /* Do Work */ });  // Slow
WithReference.Go(new WorkerClass()); // Faster
WithAnonymousReference.Go((new WorkerClass()).doWork); // Faster
WithMethod.Go(); // Even faster!
WithInlinedMthod.Go() // Fastest!

public class WithAnonymousFunction {
    public static function Go(func:Function):void { 
        func();         
    }
}

public class WorkerClass {
    public doWork() { // Do Work }
}

public class WithAnonymousReference {        
    public static function Go(func:Function) {
        func();         
    }
}

public class WithReference {
    public static function Go(cls:WorkerClass) {
        cls.doWork()
    }
}   

public class WithMethod {
    public static function Go() {
        doWork();
    }

    public static function doWork():void { // Do Work }
}

public class WithInlinedMethod {
    public static function Go() {
        // Do Work
    }
}
```

One thing I'm not sure about is the performance difference between using a concrete class vs an interface.

Comment: thanks! I might move the implementation code examples to the top; your explanation doesn't make sense without them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var someFunction:Function = function():void{}
```

will perform more slowly than

```
public function someFunction():void{}
```

Whether the difference is sufficient that it matters much is a different story entirely.  I think there's plenty of value in using function typed variables as temporary callbacks for "events" (Not Flash AS3 Events, but the generic meaning of the word "event") that don't occur once per update loop.  Even inside an update loop, this strategy is *far* more performance-friendly than using the Flash native event dispatch model (particularly if you're using event bubbling, which is an absolute pig).

Of course he may also be referring to the Law of Demeter, which is a means of encapsulating deeply nested "has-a" type relationships such that you don't care if "doFoo()" requires 10 object references and function calls under the hood as long as foo is done.  The Law of Demeter can be very performance intensive depending on just how deep the call stack goes when you call doFoo().

As to the question in your comment, it's easy enough to test yourself.  In a fla:

```
// on frame 1
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
this.addChild(textField);

var f:Function = this.stop();
var i:int = 0;
var ilen:int = 100000;

var time:int;

time = getTimer();
for(i = 0 ; i < ilen ; i++){
    f();
}
time = getTimer() - time;
textField.text = "f() :: "+String(time)+"\n";

this.gotoAndStop(2);

// on frame 2

var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
time = getTimer();
for(i = 0 ; i < ilen ; i++){
    mc.stop();
}
time = getTimer() - time;
textField.appendText("mc.stop() :: " + String(time));
this.stop();
```

I haven't tested this so there may be syntax errors.  Of course you'll need the proper imports as well.  This should be logically sound, though.

Make sure to test this in a browser, not just in the debug player or the preview player.  Your browser plugin will have better performance numbers, and will also more likely be what the end user has on their machine.

Comment: Does your anonymous function example have the same performance as referencing an object's method?